# Illegal reflective access com.thoughtworks.xstream.core(/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1) java.util.TreeMap.comparator

Tags: java, apache-camel, salesforce, spring-camel

```java
 from("direct:query")
           .setHeader("sObjectQuery", simple("SELECT name FROM account"))
            .to("salesforce:query?sObjectQuery=&sObjectClass=" + QueryRecordsAccount.class.getName()).to("log:?level=DEBUG&showBody=true");
            /*.process(exchange -> {
                Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
                log.info("--->> {}",body.getClass());
                log.info("--->> {}",body);
            });*/
```

I am facing problem with below error.

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred.

> WARNING: ****Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:*/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.11.1/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator****

> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Comment: I know nothing about the xstream library, but this speaks poorly of it.  There is no valid reason for trying to change a TreeMap’s comparator.  And changing private fields of classes in other libraries is childish hacking.